# Get X and Y coordinate Of view

Tags: iphone

I have one UITableView in My View.The name of my UITableView is tblTask.
I am using touchesBegan method to get the x and y coordinate of my view.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    NSLog(@"point........ %f .. %f",location.x,location.y);



}
```

But when I begin the touch event from the tbltask. It does not return the location.x and location.y even if tbltask is the subview of the main view. 
 I tried to disable the scrollview of the table also but nothing happen.

when I set this.

```
tbltask.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

Then it will give the coordinate but I want the coordinate of view even if tbltask interaction is enabled.

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to subclass `UITableView` and override `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:` and `touchesEnded:` methods. Don't forget to call their `[super ...]` equivalents.

Comment: ok will try. then let you know.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want here - the x,y of your view, or the x,y of your touch? Your code will return the x,y of your touch.

Comment: x,y of my view .. but because of tableview is in front of my view i cant get the x,y of my view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     UITouch *touch ;
     touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     if ([touch view] == self.view){
         CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
         NSLog(@"point........ %f .. %f",location.x,location.y);
      }
}
```